# Counting the number of emails exchanged with a given email address in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to easily count the number of emails exchanged with a given email address in Gmail? (number of emails <> number of threads)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a one simple way. By default gmail shows all the mails in the threaded view so threads can easily be seen on the top right of gmail which says `1-50 of 1350` This `1350` is the number of threads.
Now to view the total number of mails, just go to settings and turn off the "conversation view".
Save the settings and you'll be seeing something like this `1-50 of 2980`. Here `2980` is the total number of mails.

P.S. : This will show the threads and mails for the tab which you have opened like primary, updates, social etc. It would be better to turn off the tabs to view the whole report.